# Start IHostedService after Configure()

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-hosted-services

I have an .NET Core 3.1 app that serves an endpoint that describes health of application, and an IHostedService crunching through data in database.
There's a problem though, the worker function of HostedService starts processing for a long time, and as result the `Configure()` method in Startup is not called and the `/status` endpoint is not running.

I want the `/status` endpoint to start running before the HostedService kicks off. How do i start the endpoint before the Hosted Service?

Sample code

```
public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddHostedService<SomeHostedProcessDoingHeavyWork>();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapGet("/status", async context =>
            {
                await context.Response.WriteAsync("OK");
            });
        });
    }
}
```

The HostedService

```
public class SomeHostedProcessDoingHeavyWork : BackgroundService
{
    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            await MethodThatRunsForSeveralMinutes();
            await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1), stoppingToken);
        }
    }

    private async Task MethodThatRunsForSeveralMinutes()
    {
        // Process data from db....

        return;
    }
}
```

I tried to explore adding the HostedService in `Configure()`, but `app.ApplicationServices` is a ServiceProvider hence readonly.

Comment: Try moving the body of `ExecuteAsync` into a seperate method and then `await` that in ExecuteAsync ie `await DoWork(stoppingToken)`. You can also try placing `await Task.Delay(1);` as the first line. Creation of services  are blocked on until they become asynchronous. I'd expect it to become so immediately at your first await, but similar examples in the docs use the first  mechanism I suggest

Comment: It worked by adding Task.Delay() before executing worker task. Will you post as answer?

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something but neither of the solutions below worked for me. I had to add service in the `Program.cs` instead of inside the `Startup.ConfigureServices`. Otherwise the server didn't actually start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using `Task.Yield()` and implementing an abstract class to encapsulate it, with optional `PreExecuteAsyncInternal` hook and errorhandler `ExecuteAsyncExceptionHandler`

```
public abstract class AsyncBackgroundService : BackgroundService
{
    protected ILogger _logger;
    private readonly TimeSpan _delay;

    protected AsyncBackgroundService(ILogger logger, TimeSpan delay)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _delay = delay;
    }

    public virtual Task PreExecuteAsyncInternal(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        // Override in derived class
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public virtual void ExecuteAsyncExceptionHandler(Exception ex)
    {
        // Override in derived class
    }

    public abstract Task ExecuteAsyncInternal(CancellationToken stoppingToken);

    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {   
        // Prevent BackgroundService from locking before Startup.Configure()
        await Task.Yield();

        _logger.LogInformation("Running...");

        await PreExecuteAsyncInternal(stoppingToken);

        while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            try
            {
                await ExecuteAsyncInternal(stoppingToken);
                await Task.Delay(_delay, stoppingToken);
            }
            catch (TaskCanceledException)
            {
                // Deliberate
                break;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.LogCritical($"Error executing {nameof(ExecuteAsyncInternal)} in {GetType().Name}", ex.InnerException);

                ExecuteAsyncExceptionHandler(ex);

                break;
            }
        }

        _logger.LogInformation("Stopping...");
    }
}
```

Comment: the `await Task.Yield();` line needs to be the first line in the method.
The reason for it is to "release" the Task so that Host.StartAsync can continue.
If any preceding code blocks (yes, even awaited stuff can block) then the Host will block at this service and not continue with starting any others.

In your snippet... you will get this behavior as a side effect, assuming that `PreExecuteAsyncInternal` can return async. Putting it in the loop "works" but just putting it as line one will give you the behavior you're looking for.

Answer (score 10):

I think proposed solutions are a kind of workarounds.

If you add your hosted service *inside* **ConfigureServices()**, it will be started **before** Kestrel because the *GenericWebHostService* (that in fact runs Kestrel), is added in Program.cs when you call

```
.ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
        webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>()
)
```

**so it's always being added as lasts.**

To launch your hosted service **after** Kestrel, just chain another call to

`.ConfigureServices(s => s.AddYourServices())`
after the call to `ConfigureWebHostDefaults()`.

Something like this:

```
IHostBuilder hostBuilder = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
 .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder => webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>())
 .ConfigureServices(s => { 
      s.AddHostedService<SomeHostedProcessDoingHeavyWork>();
  });
```

and you should be done.

Comment: Could this answer be updated for .NET 6+? The sample code provided doesn't exist anymore now that there's no explicit Startup.cs (at least, by default)

Comment: It works perfectly. For those who need to implement the code above, I suggest to rewrite .NET 6/7 (the "Minimal Hosting") to old style, as the new is cosmetic and the vast amount of docs are in old style. Also, I noticed they didn't worry to make "scape doors", so we can have access to extending at full force. So, for advanced scenarios, it seems we are stuck in the old style.

Answer (score 3):

ExecuteAsync should return a Task and it should do so quickly. From the documentation (emphasis mine)

> ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken) is called to run the background
>   service. The implementation returns a Task that represents the entire
>   lifetime of the background service. **No further services are started
>   until ExecuteAsync becomes asynchronous, such as by calling await.
>   Avoid performing long, blocking initialization work in ExecuteAsync.**
>   The host blocks in StopAsync(CancellationToken) waiting for
>   ExecuteAsync to complete.

You should be able to get around this by moving your logic into a seperate method and awaiting *that*

```
protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken) 
{ 
    await BackgroundProcessing(stoppingToken);
}

private async Task BackgroundProcessing(CancellationToken stoppingToken) 
{ 
    while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
    { 
        await MethodThatRunsForSeveralMinutes();
        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1), stoppingToken); 
    }
}
```

Alternatively you might just be able to add an await at the start of the method:

```
protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken) 
{ 
    await Task.Yield();
    while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
    { 
        await MethodThatRunsForSeveralMinutes();
        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1), stoppingToken); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

For anyone stumbling over this:
Andrew Lock has a very nice solution on his [Blog](https://andrewlock.net/finding-the-urls-of-an-aspnetcore-app-from-a-hosted-service-in-dotnet-6/), using the `IHostApplicationLifetime`:

```
public class TestHostedService: BackgroundService
{
    private readonly IHostApplicationLifetime _lifetime;
    private readonly TaskCompletionSource _source = new();
    public TestHostedService(IHostApplicationLifetime lifetime)
    {
        _lifetime = lifetime;
        _lifetime.ApplicationStarted.Register(() => _source.SetResult()); 
    }

    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        await _source.Task.ConfigureAwait(false); // Wait for the task to complete!
        await DoSomethingAsync();
    }
}
```

A potential Problem occours if the application doesn't start up: If the `ApplicationStarted` token never triggers, then the `TaskCompletionSource.Task` will never complete, and the `ExecuteAsync` method will never complete. To solve this problem, you can use this approach:

```
public class TestHostedService: BackgroundService
{
    private readonly IHostApplicationLifetime _lifetime;
    public TestHostedService(IHostApplicationLifetime lifetime)
    {
        _lifetime = lifetime;
    }

    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        if (!await WaitForAppStartup(_lifetime, stoppingToken))
        {
            return;
        }

        await DoSomethingAsync();
    }

    static async Task<bool> WaitForAppStartup(IHostApplicationLifetime lifetime, CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        var startedSource = new TaskCompletionSource();
        var cancelledSource = new TaskCompletionSource();

        using var reg1 = lifetime.ApplicationStarted.Register(() => startedSource.SetResult());
        using var reg2 = stoppingToken.Register(() => cancelledSource.SetResult());

        Task completedTask = await Task.WhenAny(startedSource.Task, cancelledSource.Task);

        // If the completed tasks was the "app started" task, return true, otherwise false
        return completedTask == startedSource.Task;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a great solution.. especially for more recent versions of NET

Answer (score 0):

`await Task.Yield` didn't work for me.

The simplest obvious solution:

**Startup.cs**

```
public class Startup
{
   public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
   {
      // Implementation omitted
      services.AddSingleton<ApplicationRunState>();
   }

   public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
   {
      // Implementation omitted
      app.MarkConfigurationAsFinished();
   }
}
```

**StartupExtensions.cs**

```
public static void MarkConfigurationAsFinished(this IApplicationBuilder builder)
{
   builder.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<ApplicationRunState>()
      .ConfigurationIsFinished = true;
}
```

**ExampleBackgroundService.cs**

```
protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
{
    while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        if (!_serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<ApplicationRunState>()
            .ConfigurationIsFinished)
        {
            await Task.Delay(5000);
            continue;
        }

        // Further implementation omitted
    }
}
```

Comment: Your solution works, but there is a better form of Task.Delay. Make use of SemaphoreSlim which releases immediately.

Answer (score 0):

The [source code](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/0110d83a9522043329b450f53fce53c27ec8522e/src/DefaultBuilder/src/WebApplicationBuilder.cs#L380C46-L380C78) of the newer `WebApplicationBuilder` recommends leveraging `ConfigureContainer` to achieve this behavior, though I personally don't find that to be the cleanest solution and seems likely it will break in the future.

```cs
    /// <summary>
    /// Builds the <see cref="WebApplication"/>.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>A configured <see cref="WebApplication"/>.</returns>
    public WebApplication Build()
    {
        // ConfigureContainer callbacks run after ConfigureServices callbacks including the one that adds GenericWebHostService by default.
        // One nice side effect is this gives a way to configure an IHostedService that starts after the server and stops beforehand.
        _hostApplicationBuilder.Services.Add(_genericWebHostServiceDescriptor);
        Host.ApplyServiceProviderFactory(_hostApplicationBuilder);
        _builtApplication = new WebApplication(_hostApplicationBuilder.Build());
        return _builtApplication;
    }
```