# HostedService starting on startup

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection

I am working on an web API that is supposed to handle some long running tasks, like calling another external API for thousands of calls and storing the returned data. I am using DI to inject a Service into my controller to handle the logic. That service is a hosted service, since that is the most fitting service type to my understanding.

My problem is, that the StartAsync() method is being called whenever the API is being started - not only when I call the method through an API controller. Does anyone know how to disable the framework calling that method? Is using a hosted service necessary or even advisable for my situation?

Honestly I only understand the difference between Singleton, Transient and Scoped services, and don't really understand what a hosted service is supposed to be.

Comment: Singleton, Transient and Scoped services are life scope of an object. On the other end StartAsync seems to be a custom function. Can you share code so that we understand your problem? "StartAsync() method is being called whenever the API is being started" - Why dont you stop calling the StartAsync() method from the startup class?

Comment: @Rahatur HostedServices are a type of service like Singleton, Scoped and Transient. StartAsync is a method from the IHostedService interface. What I implemented is not relevant to this question, besides maybe the fact that I registered the service without further configuration.

Comment: @Rahatur I am not calling the method from Startup. I only call the method through the controller myself, it is being called by the framework without my initiation

Comment: Got your point. I have posted a solution to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It is the default behavior of IHostedService to start executing right after the application pipeline is configured and ApplicationStarted event is triggered by the framework.

The default behavior can be changed so that the StartAsync method runs after the app's pipeline has been configured. For that add the hosted service after calling CreateBuilder:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddHostedService<YourServieName>();
```

And if you want to delay the service further then follow the answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61873214/218408).

Please note that the ExecuteAsync should run as soon as possible because the StopAsync will wait for it to complete. Basically what you do is move the body of the ExecuteAsync to another method and delay that one.
For that reason there is a work around discussed on that thread.